# CloudFoundry login error : "wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)"

Tags: authentication, cloud-foundry

I just registerd a new account with CloudFOundry and am having trouble loging in through vmc.

I set target ok to http://api.cloudfoundry.com

Here is result from vmc info command

```
VMware's Cloud Application Platform

target: http://api.cloudfoundry.com
version: 0.999
support: http://support.cloudfoundry.com
```

When I run following command:

> vmc login myemail@address.com --password myPasswd

I get following result:

```
target: http://api.cloudfoundry.com

Authenticating... FAILED
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
For more information, see ~/.vmc/crash
```

Here is ~/vmc/crash content

```
Time of crash:   Wed Feb 06 11:57:38 -0500 2013

ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/cli/start/login.rb:74:in `login'
vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/cli/start/login.rb:74:in `login'
interact-0.5.2/lib/interact/progress.rb:98:in `with_progress'
vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/cli/start/login.rb:72:in `login'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/base.rb:61:in `send'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/base.rb:61:in `run'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/command.rb:68:in `invoke'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/command.rb:82:in `instance_exec'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/command.rb:82:in `invoke'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/base.rb:50:in `execute'
vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/cli.rb:106:in `execute'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership.rb:45:in `start' vmc-0.4.7/bin/vmc:11
/usr/bin/vmc:19:in `load' /usr/bin/vmc:19
```

I cannot believe that I can't get search result regarding this issue.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and here is a solution:

find login.rb file (on my pc: C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\vmc-0.4.7\lib\vmc\cli\start\login.rb)

edit this file and find line:

```
info[:token] = client.login(credentials)
```

and rewrite to:

`info[:token] = client.login(credentials[:username], credentials[:password])`

and it should work :)

Comment: Actually, this change has been made in the latest version of the vmc source code (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vmc/blob/master/lib/vmc/cli/start/login.rb#L46). The latest pre-release versions of vmc should have this change. You can try it by doing `gem install vmc --pre`.

Answer (score 0):

I have to recommend the login.rb as a workaround. Installing the --pre (0.5.0beta20) yielded a broken dependency :

```
Failed to load tunnel-dummy-vmc-plugin:
Unable to activate tunnel-dummy-vmc-plugin-0.0.2, because cfoundry-0.5.0 conflicts with cfoundry (~> 0.4.0)
```

Comment: I had that same issue today, and resolved it by removing all the copies of the cfoundry gem and vmc and reinstalling vmc --pre

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem with an incompatibility between to gems - `vmc 0.4.7` and `cfoundry 0.4.20`. This should be fixed with the release of `cfoundry 0.4.21`, which was published to rubygems on Feb 8.